# take screenshot of multiple views – Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, screenshot

I have a baseview (UIView) and a background image (UIImageView). (The background image is NOT a subview of the base view.) I also have more views on `self.view` that I don't want to be included. When a button is clicked I screenshot is taken like this:

```
CGRect rect = [baseView bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[baseView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(capturedImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),nil);
```

This are the baseview:

```
baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.origin.x), ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.origin.y), ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width), ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height))];
baseView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:baseView];
```

This is the background image:

```
backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
backgroundImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImage];
```

The screenshot obviously only captures the baseview but I want the background image to be captured in the image as well. Is there a way to do this?
I could solve this by adding the background image as backgroundColor of the baseview instead but I don't want it to be repeated to fit the screen.

Comment: If you have only these two subviews on your self.view then take screenshot from self.view

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan But I have more views on self.view that I don't want to be included, sorry I didn't mention that in the question

Comment: Temporarily set the unwanted views to hidden, take the screenshot, and turn em back on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just render both in the context:

```
CGRect rect = [baseView bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[backgroundImage.layer renderInContext:context];
[baseView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```